# Returning to Old position pointed by FileInputStream

Tags: java

I'm reading data from a textfile. But after the code leaves from the main class to the Factory class, I want the empTextStreamIn to continue from where it left off. But for me its showing only the data related to the Salaried class. Kindly tell me what changes should I make in my Main class. My textfile has data related to all types of employees.

Assume all the necessary data.

Below are the code snippets

## Main.java

```
char valueInFirstColumn = 0;
while((valueInFirstColumn!=' ' || valueInFirstColumn!='\n') && (empTextStreamIn.available()!=0))
        {
            employeeFileParser = empTextStreamIn.read();
            valueInFirstColumn = (char)employeeFileParser;
            Factory f = new Factory(empTextStreamIn,valueInFirstColumn);
        }
```

==============

## Factory.java

```
public Factory(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn, char valueInFirstColumn) throws IOException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        //do
        //{
            if(valueInFirstColumn == '1')
            {
                Salaried slr = new Salaried(empTextStreamIn);
                slr.readData();
                slr.printData();
                //System.out.println(empTextStreamIn.read());
            }
            else if(valueInFirstColumn == '2')
            {
                Hourly hr = new Hourly(empTextStreamIn);
                hr.readData();
                hr.printData();
            }
            else if(valueInFirstColumn == '3')
            {
                Commissioned com = new Commissioned(empTextStreamIn);
                com.readData();
                com.printData();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Unkown Department");
            }
        }
```

=====================

Employee.java

```
public Employee(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        do 
        {
            FileParser = empTextStreamIn.read();
            //System.out.println(FileParser);

            if(FileParser != -1)
            {
                parsed_text+=(char)FileParser;
            }

        } while(FileParser != -1);
        System.out.println(parsed_text);
        //FileParser = empTextStreamIn.read();
        //parsed_text+=(char)FileParser;
        //System.out.println(parsed_text);

        /*for (String everyLine : parsed_text.split("\\n"))
        {*/
                tokens1 = parsed_text.split("\\s+");
                //System.out.println(tokens1);
                /*String var1 = tokens1[0];
                empType = Integer.parseInt(var1);
                if(empType == 1)
                {*/
                    var1 = tokens1[1];
                    var2 = tokens1[2];
                    var3 = tokens1[3];
                    var4 = tokens1[4];
                /*}
        }*/



    }
    protected void readData()
    {
        EmpID = var1;
        DeptID = var2;

    }
    protected void printData()
    {
        System.out.print("Emp ID:"+EmpID+"  DeptID:"+DeptID);
    }
```

==============================

Salaried.java

```
public class Salaried extends Employee
{
    double salary;  //Unique detail for Salaried class

    Salaried()
    {

    }

    Salaried(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) throws IOException 
    {
        super(empTextStreamIn);
    }
    protected void readData()
    {
        super.readData();
        salary = Double.parseDouble(var3);
    }
    protected void printData()
    {
        super.printData();
        System.out.println("   Salary:"+salary);
    }

}
```

=====================================

Commissioned.java

```
Commissioned(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) throws IOException
    {
        super(empTextStreamIn);
    }
    protected void readData()
    {
        super.readData();
        sales = Double.parseDouble(var3);
    }
    protected void printData()
    {
        super.printData();
        System.out.println("   Sales:"+sales);
    }
```

===========================================

Hourly.txt

```
Hourly(FileInputStream empFileInputStream) throws IOException
    {
        super(empFileInputStream);
    }
    protected void readData()
    {
        super.readData();
        hours = Double.parseDouble(var3);
        rate = Double.parseDouble(var4);
    }
    protected void printData()
    {
        super.printData();
        System.out.println("   Sales:"+hours+"   Rate:"+rate);
```

## }

Employee.txt

The first value is a code representing the employee type: 1 is salaried, 2 is hourly, and 3 is commission. 
The next column is the employee ID, 
the next the department ID of the employee. 
The next column varies depending on the employee type. 
-   For salaried employees it is their salary per annum. 
-   (For hourly employees it is the number of hours to be paid. Overtime (1.5) is paid for all time over 40 hours. 
-   Following the hours in column five is the rate of pay for the employee.)

```
1 23938475683 1111 62000
2 30495848484 2222 40    21.5
3 40394833333 3333 30000
2 48584842283 2232 45    10
2 38485849494 2222 42.5  15
1 34345564433 1111 56000
3 98605050393 3333 12000
3 00033432738 3333 17000
```

======

Required Output

```
Employee #23938475683  Dept# 1111    Salary:$62000
Employee #30495848484  Dept# 2222  Hours:40  Rate:$21.5
Employee #40394833333  Dept# 3333  Sales:$30000
Employee #48584842283  Dept# 2232  Hours:45  Rate:$10
Employee #38485849494  Dept# 2222  Hours:42.5  Rate:$15
Employee #34345564433  Dept# 1111  Salary:$56000
Employee #98605050393  Dept# 3333  Sales:$12000
Employee #00033432738  Dept# 3333  Sales:$17000
```

===============================

Obtained output

```
Employee #:23938475683  Dept#:1111   Salary:62000.0
```

I'm not getting the other lines.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Your inputStream is passed to the class Factory and after that to the class Salaried by reference. This means that you are using the same object over multiple classes. Where do you want to continue to read when you return to your main? What do you expect from input, a File or some console input manually?

Comment: What happens in the constructor of Commissioned, Salaried and hourly, and what happens in their readData and printData methods?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to return to an earlier point in a `FileInputStream`.

In this situation you should instead ensure that the employee constructor only reads the data which describes its corresponding employee instead. The do-while condition in the `Employee` constructor is the culprit. `while(FileParser != -1);` basically means "continue doing this until we reached the end of the file. More suitably, in this particular case, you should probably use `while(FileParser != '\n');` which would mean "continue doing this until we reached the end of the line".

What editor are you using to write your code? If you are using Eclipse (a pretty common editor for writing java code), i would suggest you learn how to use the debugger. Have a look at a tutorial over [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html). The most relevant sections to get started would be: **4.1. Setting Breakpoints**, **4.2. Starting the Debugger** and **4.4. Variables**. Using a debugger would help you pinpoint what is wrong in cases like this. The debugger will step through the code lines one at a time, and you would soon notice that the while loop executes too many times.

Completely unrelated advice: Java developers usually follow the convention of starting variable names with lower case letters. Hence, I would suggest you e.g. use `empId` instead of capitalizing the first letter.